# "Adding" functions to a shared object?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have a closed sourced application that includes an interpreter that dynamically loads symbols from a shared object, libclosedsource.so, which is closed source. I would like to add a few API extensions of my own. Now the application in question loads the file using dlopen, so I can basically replace libclosedsource.so with whatever library I want. However, that library should contain a superset of the symbols exported by the original.

My question: Is it possible to rename the original shared object to say libclosedsource-orig.so and create my own libclosedsource.so, so that upon loading libclosedsource.so the application will be able to see the symbols exported in libclosedsource-orig.so?

My assumption is somehow that the answer, unfortunately, is no, since symbol loading doesn't seem to be transitive. I'm open to any other suggestions for accomplishing this.

EDIT: The original library contains about 300 functions.

Comment: I could do a full implementation of the whole interface through its headers and forward the calls, but it contains a few hundred functions, so I would need to write scripts that generate the code.

Comment: All free functions.

Comment: Look for "filter" in `man ld`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to SoronelHaetir answer, wrapping calls to original library can be automated via [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so):

```
$ implib-gen.py libclosedsource-orig.so
$ gcc new-code.c libclosedsource-orig.tramp.S libclosedsource-orig.init.c -shared -fPIC -o libclosedsource.so
```

Note that you don't need headers of `libclosedsource-orig.so`, just the binary itself. `libclosedsource.so` will load `libclosedsource-orig.so` at startup and redirect calls to original APIs to it.

Comment: Cool. This does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the signatures of all the exported functions this would be easy though fairly tedious, just re-implement all the functions and pass them through to calls to the original library.

Also, take a look at: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70302/Redirecting-functions-in-shared-ELF-libraries

Comment: Yeah, I know of this approach. Should have mentioned that the interface is a few hundred functions, so this is quite non-trivial to do and would require parsing the headers etc.

Comment: @EdvardFagerholm Generation of forwarding APIs can be automated via [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so).